# SQL calculating sickness days over months

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, reporting-services, calculation

I've currently got a very poorly written query which works out actual sickness days over months (example - if an employee has a sickness start date of 01/01/2017 and end date of 01/03/2017, it will calculate all of the sick days they SHOULD have worked (Mon - Fri for example, however, there is no set work pattern) and split the days over the months they were sick). The current report takes over 10 minutes to run a fiscal year.

I'd like to re-write the query so that it performs better and is (probably) more accurate.

I have three main tables to work from:

- An 'activity' table which the employee fills in their start times and end times. As this records all activities, their lunch breaks are shown as a gap in activity - [-----] LUNCH BREAK [---------]
- A sickness table which shows Start Date and End Date of sickness
- A calendar table which has dates in all formats you could ever imagine

Examples of tables below.

Sickness Table:

```
 EMP ID | Start Date       | End Date         | Location ID 
--------|------------------|------------------|-------------
 1      | 01/02/2017 08:30 | 19/03/2017 23:59 | 20          
 2      | 04/02/2017 08:30 | 06/02/2017 23:59 | 4           
 3      | 02/02/2017 09:00 | 03/02/2017 23:59 | 15          
 4      | 03/02/2017 08:45 | 03/02/2017 23:59 | 7           
 5      | 05/02/2017 08:30 | 10/04/2017 23:59 | 9
```

Activity Table:

```
| EMP ID | Start Date       | End Date         | Activity Type | Location ID | Group ID |
|--------|------------------|------------------|---------------|-------------|----------|
| 1      | 02/01/2017 13:18 | 02/01/2017 17:00 | 11            | 20          | 1        |
| 1      | 02/01/2017 08:30 | 02/01/2017 12:12 | 11            | 20          | 1        |
| 2      | 02/01/2017 13:18 | 02/01/2017 17:00 | 13            | 4           | 4        |
| 2      | 02/01/2017 08:30 | 02/01/2017 12:12 | 13            | 4           | 4        |
| 3      | 02/01/2017 13:18 | 02/01/2017 17:00 | 1             | 15          | 2        |
| 3      | 02/01/2017 08:30 | 02/01/2017 12:12 | 1             | 15          | 2        |
| 4      | 02/01/2017 13:18 | 02/01/2017 17:00 | 4             | 7           | 5        |
| 4      | 02/01/2017 08:30 | 02/01/2017 12:12 | 4             | 7           | 5        |
| 5      | 02/01/2017 13:18 | 02/01/2017 17:00 | 10            | 9           | 3        |
| 5      | 02/01/2017 08:30 | 02/01/2017 12:12 | 10            | 9           | 3        |
| 5      | 02/01/2017 17:00 | 02/01/2017 18:00 | 3             | 9           | 3        |
```

The results will be used in SSRS in a table/matrix which will look as follows:

```
| Group | Location | Total Sickness Days - Months (fiscal year -   April-Mar) |
|-------|----------|----------------------------------------------------------|
| 1     | 20       | xx                                                       |
| 2     | 4        | xx                                                       |
| 3     | 15       | xx                                                       |
| 4     | 7        | xx                                                       |
| 5     | 9        | xx                                                       |
```

I'm unsure of what the best practice would be for such a query. Any help will be much appreciated and thanks in advance.

EDIT: Logic.

- A sick day is counted when someone is sick for more than 50% of their working day. If someone goes home sick after they've worked 50% of their working day, it doesn't count as a day.
- Shifts won't overlap another day

Comment: Is a sick day counted as any sickness on a particular date?  What if someone leaves early due to sickness do you still count this as a whole day?  Does anyones shift go over two dates (working past midnight).  Let us know the logic you want to use for your calculations.

Comment: So as I understand it each shift has multiple activity rows.  Unfortunately without a shift identifier that is unique per each individual shift I don't think you will be able to calculate this as you want to.  As you allude in your original question the current code is probably not accurate.

Comment: I see what you're saying. If a shift started at 8PM and finished at 6AM the following day, the sickness day would be the day which the shift started - would this change things?

Comment: The problem is we have no way of knowing what constitutes a shift.  Say I work 2 days in a row.  On both days I start at 8 pm have lunch at 1 am and finish at 6 am.  So for each shift there will be 3 records 1 record on the first date and 2 on the second date.  So that means there will be 3 records on the second date but they are for 2 different shifts.  If there is no way to determine which rows relate to which shift we can't calculate what you need to.

Comment: Let's ignore the fact that there are some employees who have contracts that *can* go over a day, how would I go about doing the other cases where a sickness day lies within an actual day? Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it would be possible.  Unfortunately I've just been hit with a new urgent request so can't spend any more time on this today. With your requirements though it would be better to create a table using a stored procedure that breaks up each step instead of trying to do it in one query.  Then point your report to that table.

Comment: FYI there is currently no overlap between your `Activity` dates and your `Sickness` dates.  I am assuming this is a typo?

Comment: @iamdave This was just example data.

Comment: @ADicks  I get that, but if you want appropriate assistance, you need to provide us with representative data.  At present any solution we come up with won't show any results on your given data as there is no overlap, so we would have to build our own test data anyway, to help you solve your problem.  This is going to either confuse or simply put a lot of people off helping.